# Centering images in CSS responsive photo gallery w/caption

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a simple responsive CSS photo gallery where 
(a) images are centered vertically within each row
(b) each row of images is centered horizontally
(c) the caption is centered horizontally below each image

I've been trying the following code:  http://www.terragalleria.com/tmp/test-align.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>

<style>
.centered_block {
clear: both;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
}

.img_with_link {
padding: 0.5em;
float: left;
display: table;
width: 240px;
height: 240px;
text-align: center;
}

.img_with_link_inside {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

div.img_with_link img {
display: inline;
margin: 0.5em;
}

.link_with_img {
}

</style>

</head>

<BODY>

<div class="centered_block">

<div class = "img_with_link">
<div class = "img_with_link_inside">
<img src = "http://www.terragalleria.com/images/np-pacific/olym11102.small.jpeg">
<div class = "link_with_img">
Olympic
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "img_with_link">
<div class = "img_with_link_inside">
<img src = "http://www.terragalleria.com/images/np-pacific/redw1447.small.jpeg">  
<div class = "link_with_img">
Redwood
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "img_with_link">
<div class = "img_with_link_inside">
<img src = "http://www.terragalleria.com/images/np-pacific/chis1466.small.jpeg">  
<div class = "link_with_img">
Channel Islands
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is the resulting browser window:

[image: resulting browser window]
<sub>(source: [terragalleria.com](http://www.terragalleria.com/tmp/medium.jpg))</sub>

Here is what I am trying to get:

[image: desired browser window]
<sub>(source: [terragalleria.com](http://www.terragalleria.com/tmp/medium-desired.jpg))</sub>

Note that the difficulty here seems to be caused by the caption. I am able to get that result (meeting criteria (a) and (b)) without the caption, see http://www.terragalleria.com/mobile/np.olympic.html

Any ideas on how to fix the code ? Thank

Comment: .img_with_link  should not have float:left. Remove that to see what happens and if it doesn't work add clear:both; And also remove table display properties; you shouldn't need it.

Comment: frenchie beat me to it, but this worked in my browser:

   ` .img_with_link {
      padding: 0.5em;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 240px;
      height: 240px;
      text-align: center;
    }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestions. If I just remove  float:left then I get one image per row, not my intent, which is to have images fill-up the rows.

Comment: By changing display: table to display: inline-block; the rows are correctly centered, but there are two problems. First, images are not vertically centered (the reason why I had to use display:table so that vertical-align: middle; works). Second, the images are not properly centered. You can see the spaces between the two middle images is now not equal at http://www.terragalleria.com/tmp/test-align1.html (bronze's code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it's good like that:

```
.centered_block {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center; 
}

.img_with_link {
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.img_with_link_inside {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Only tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11.
`display: table-cell;` is used to allow `vertical-align: middle` and in order to center something your block need to have a width. (which can be calculated if all children have a width I think...) Also, I add `display: inline-block;` to replace the `float: left`.

Comment: Thanks, I have also tested successfully on Safari (both OSX and iOS).

Answer (score 0):

i hope to help, might put a main div and images within this(an illustrative example)

```
<a>http://jsfiddle.net/step/k5yb8wqo/</a>
```